# UITableview background view colour -iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, background

I have an UITableview controller without an XIB.
I set the background colour of the tableview by doing this:

```
[self.tableView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:
                                    [UIImage imageNamed:@"MmyImage.png"]]];
```

My image is a gradient image, so eventhough the above code is ok, it redraws the image for each cell when the tableview goes to edit view, and it appears as lines which is not looking elegant.

I would like to set the tableviews background to clear colour and set the superview's colour to the image, so that the tableview transitions smoothly over the superview. However the below code does not work:

```
[self.view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:
                               [UIImage imageNamed:@"myImage.png"]]];
[self.tableView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
```

This makes the background completely white, I dont know why.

Help appreciated..thanks.

Edited:new code but this does not work as well:

```
   UIImageView * imgBg = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[[UIImage imageNamed:@"myImage.png"] stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:6 topCapHeight:6]];
     imgBg.frame = self.tableView.window.bounds;
    [self.tableView.superview addSubview:imgBg];
//[self.view addSubview:imgBg];
    //[self.tableView.window sendSubviewToBack:imgBg];
    //[self.view  bringSubviewToFront:self.tableView];
    [self.tableView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    [imgBg release];
```

Comment: Have you tried: `self.tableView.opaque = NO;`?

Comment: It's possible that cell's background is white as well.

Comment: tried opaque, does not work..the cells background have an individual grey gradient image, which works ok..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In a custom `UITableViewController` subclass, `self.view` will return the same as `self.tableView`. So what you're doing there is altering the same object. In the end, you get to see the `UIWindow`. So to get the desired result, you should do this –

```
[self.view.window setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"myImage.png"]]];
[self.tableView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
```

`UITableView` has a `backgroundView` property. Use it.

```
aTableView.backgroundView = [[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:aTableView.bounds] autorelease];
aTableView.backgroundView.backgroundColor = backgroundColor;
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the suggestion, tried, but does not work...it shows plain white colour as the background with above.

Answer (score 0):

then your second code will be right, except:

```
[self.view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:
                               [UIImage imageNamed:@"myImage.png"]]];
```

replace this:

```
UIImageView * imgBg = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[[UIImage imageNamed:@"myImage.png"] stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:6 topCapHeight:6]];
imgBg.frame = self.view.bounds;
[self.view addSubview:imgBg];
[self.view sendSubviewToBack:imgBg];
```

**Edit**
I think:
`[self.tableView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:0.0 green:0.0 blue:0.0 alpha:0.0]];` will helps, that is the only difference now.

Comment: I have the cells background colour set ok. what I need is the tableviews background colour.

Comment: Hi, thanks, but does not work still. I have edited my answer with my latest code. I am trying out options in the comments as well.

Comment: Please append full table view initializaton to your question, because i'm out of ideas. The code above worked for me. So the ghost is somewhere else...

Answer (score 0):

First in your xib file, add a parent view. add table view in that parent view. set parent view's background color to your desired background. then set your tableview's background color to [UIColor clearColor].

Check also, if your table view is a group table style or not? if it is group table style, then the cell have distinct background. Then you need to clear the background of each cell. The best way to do is,

1. create a blank `UIView *bkview = [[UIView alloc]  initWithRect:CGRect(0,0)];`
2. set this
   as your cells background view.

I hope this will work.

Comment: Hi, as I mentioned, there is no XIB..so unfortunately I cannot edit it.